# Explicit formula for the moment map of toric manifold

Tags: reference-request, sg.symplectic-geometry, toric-varieties

Let $P$ be a Delzant polytope in $M\otimes{\mathbb R}\cong \mathbb R^n$, and it is well-known that we can associate to it a toric manifold $X=X_P$ with the moment map $\pi: X\to P$.

*I would like to explicitly describe the restriction of the moment map $\pi_0:=\pi|_{(\mathbb C^*)^n}$ on the torus $(\mathbb C^*)^n\subset X$.*

Denote all the vertices of $P$ by $m_1,\dots, m_k\in M_{\mathbb R}$. Suppose all $m_i\in M$, then each $m_i$ corresponds to a function $\chi^{m_i}: (\mathbb C^*)^n\to \mathbb C$, and the moment map is given by the formula
$$
x \mapsto  \frac{\sum_i|\chi^{m_i}(x)|\cdot m_i}{\sum_i |\chi^{m_i}(x)|^2} \in M_{\mathbb R}
$$

> **Question**:
>
> (1) When we drop the condition $m_i\in M$, namely $m_i\in M_{\mathbb R}\setminus M$, what will happen? I think the issue is $\chi^{m_i}$ is not well-defined.
>
> (2) When we allow $P$ to be unbounded, can we find the moment map explicitly?

Can we obtain a similar formula for either Case (1) or (2) above? This might be standard, but I fail to find a reference.